# What is the shortcut key for replace text in all files in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

How do I execute the "Replace" command with a keyboard shortcut?

I can't seem to find the "command" in the default keymap for OS X.

I know the single file replace all shortcut is `control + option + enter`, but that doesn't work in this case. This is in OS X, but it probably applies to Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

20 minutes of research turned up nothing.

Attempts:

1. Opened up the `Find in Files` panel and tried lots of combinations. No luck.
2. Browsed the `keybindings` file for anything bound to the `find_in_files` panel. No luck
3. Browsed the official [Sublime Text API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html). No luck.
4. Browsed the unofficial [list of commands](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/commands.html). No luck.

This feels like a big oversight...

**update**: This is not implemented. Here is the official [feature request](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/89699-replace-button-in-find-panel-does-not-have-a-keybinding/).

Comment: I really wish they implemented this too :-(

Comment: Still waiting #2016.

Comment: Still waiting #mid2017.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + shift + F`

now you can add files and folder where you want to find and replace in all files.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Alt + Enter works for me in the latest Sublime Text 2